# Insertar un array en una posicion dentro de otro

Tags: c++, array, punteros, insert

Estoy haciendo un ejercicio de `POO` pero con punteros, y tengo que insertar un array dentro de otro en la posición que se pida, sin sobrescribir ni perder los que están, solo desplazarlo.

En la función `void IntArr::addElement(int pos,int qtty,int *vec)` hago exactamente eso, pero como verán me complique mucho la vida para hacerlo.

¿No hay una forma más eficiente de hacerlo para evitar tantas líneas de código?

Algunas referencias:

- `qtty` es la cantidad de elementos que quiero pasar del vector a insertar.
- `pos` es la posición de la que quiero insertar.
- `vec` es el vector a insertar
- `p` vector dinámico a donde voy a insertar valores
- `used` cantidad de elementos usados del vector p
- `size` tamaño del vector p

Les dejo el código de las funciones, pero si necesitan la clase completa y el main para entender que es lo que necesito, diganme y lo edito.

Este es mi **código**:

```
void IntArr::addElement(int pos,int qtty,int *vec){
  verificarPos(pos);
  redimensionador(qtty);

  //Iterador de los vectores auxiliares
  int j=0;

  //Vemos la cantidad de elementos a desplazar
  int cantDesp;
  cantDesp = used - pos;

  //Creamos el vector auxiliar con la cantidad de elementos a desplazar
  int vAux[cantDesp];

  //Recorremos el array original para guardar los elementos a desplazar
  for(int i=pos;i<used;i++){
    //cout<<endl<<"vAux["<<j<<"] = "<<vAux[j]<<" --> p["<<i<<"] = "<<p[i]; //DEBUG
    vAux[j] = p[i];
    j++;
  }

  //Vemos hasta donde llegan los nuevos items a agregar
  int espNew;
  espNew = pos + qtty;
  j=0; //Reinicio iterador

  //Agregamos los nuevos items al vector p[]
  for(int i=pos;i<espNew;i++){
    p[i] = vec[j];
    j++;
  }

  //Calculamos la pos hasta donde irán los items desplazados
  int pAux;
  pAux = used + qtty;
  j=0; //Reinicio iterador

  //Utilizamos el vAux para agregar los items salvados
  for(int i=used-1;i<pAux;i++){
    p[i] = vAux[j];
    j++;
  }
  used += qtty;
}

//Verificador
void IntArr::redimensionador(int cant){
  if(cant+used>size){
    if(cant > 5){
      size += cant;
    }
    else{
      size += 5 + cant;
    }
    int *temp = new int [size];
    memcpy (temp,p,used*sizeof(int));
    delete [] p;
    p = temp;
  }
}
void IntArr::verificarPos(int &pos){
  if(pos<=0){   //Si la posición es negativa o igual a cero
    pos = 0;
   }
  else if(pos>=size){ //Si la posición supera el tamaño del array
    pos = used;
  }
}
```

Comment: No puedes crear arreglos de tamaño estático con variables conocidas en tiempo de ejecución.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ¿No hay una forma más eficiente de hacerlo para evitar tantas líneas de código?

Hay varias maneras de medir la eficiencia de un algoritmo, desde la [gran O](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cota_superior_asint%C3%B3tica) hasta simplemente el estilo. Un algoritmo del tipo que describes no puede ser más eficiente que O(n).

Puedes mejorar tu algoritmo no en eficiencia si no en algo que en ocasiones suele ser mucho mejor y te ganará el respeto y admiración de tus compañeros de trabajo: Legibilidad.

#### Cosas a tener en cuenta.

- **Nombres auto-explicativos**: En los años 80 y 90, teníamos que programar en pantallas de 80 caracteres de ancho y 25 líneas de alto, hacer que el código fuese escueto, conciso y apelotonado era una necesidad. Esos tiempos han quedado (por fortuna) atrás, así que evita las variables de un sólo carácter, los acrónimos y las abreviaturas.
- **Ámbitos pequeños**: Se aconseja que el ámbito de las variables sea lo más pequeño posible; esto facilita seguir el código pues no hay que retroceder continuamente a una definición varias líneas atrás para saber la historia de una variable.
- **Inicialización**: Inicializa todas las variables, puedes hacerlo en la propia definición.
- **No reinventar la rueda**: C++ ofrece muchas utilidades que hacen tareas rutinarias, no vale la pena inventar tu propio método para ello teniendo disponibles utilidades testadas por centenares de miles de usuarios y con el aval de un estándar. Entiendo que el ejercicio de arrays te obliga a usar punteros en lugar de utilidades como `std::array` o `std::vector`, pero nada te impide usar `std::copy` o `std::copy_n`.
- **Usa objetos**: C++ es un lenguaje que (entre otros) usa el paradigma orientado a objetos; los objetos te permiten dar un sentido semántico a conjuntos de datos a la vez que agrupan datos que están íntimamente relacionados.

Esas son premisas sencillas, además tienes un error: estás creando un arreglo de tamaño estático usando de tamaño una variable cuyo valor es conocido en tiempo de ejecución, eso no es portable. Consulta las preguntas que mencionan [VLA](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=vla+%5Bc%2B%2B%5D) para más información al respecto.

#### Propuesta.

Entiendo que lo que quieres hacer es esto:

---

[image]

---

Pero también debes tener en cuenta estas otras casuísticas:

[image]

---

[image]

---

En cualquiera de los casos la tarea tiene tres pasos:

1. Crear un espacio nuevo (resultado de sumar el espacio de `array` e `into`).
2. Copiar los datos al espacio nuevo.
3. Borrar (si procede) los datos antiguos.

Tal y como ya he propuesto: usa objetos, un objeto que agrupe el puntero y el tamaño asociado al mismo facilitará tu trabajo:

```
struct my_array
{
    int quantity = 0;       // Nada de qtty, queremos un nombre legible.
    int *vector = nullptr;  // Nada de vec, queremos un nombre legible.
};
```

De esta manera tu función de inserción puede recibir dos objetos `my_array` y devolver otro `my_array` como objeto nuevo:

```
/* 'array' e 'into' son nombres que en el contexto de una función
llamada 'insert' nos dan claras pistas de lo que podemos esperar
de dicha función. La variable 'position' (no 'pos') cobra sentido
fácilmente en este contexto. */
my_array insert(const my_array &array, my_array &into, int position)
{
    // Tamaño resultante de insertar 'array' en 'into'.
    const auto size = array.quantity + into.quantity;
    // Nuevo objeto resultante de la inserción de 'array' en 'into'
    my_array result { size, new int[size]{} };

    /* (1) 'position' elementos de 'into' en 'result' desde el inicio de 'into'. */
    auto bookmark = std::copy_n(into.vector, position, result.vector);

    /* (2) todos los elementos de 'array' en 'result' desde el punto anterior. */
    bookmark = std::copy_n(array.vector, array.quantity, bookmark);

    /* (3) el resto de elementos de 'into' en 'result' desde el punto anterior. */
    std::copy_n(into.vector + position, into.quantity - position, bookmark);

    return result;
}
```

La función `std::copy_n` copia elementos del primer parámetro en el puntero del tercer parámetro, copia tantos elementos como se indique en el segundo parámetro y devuelve dónde dejó de copiar cuando finalizó la operación, por lo tanto el algoritmo es muy sencillo de seguir y escribir. Aquí te dejo una ilustración de qué pasa cuando copias `array` en el medio de `into`:

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Wandbox 三へ( へ՞ਊ ՞)へ ﾊｯﾊｯ](https://wandbox.org/permlink/EFOFcFPQk5jD9zzb)</kbd>.

Comment: Muchas gracias @Paula_plus_plus pero más de la mitad de las cosas ni las entiendo. Recién comienzo con estos temas. ¿No hay una forma más sencilla? Agradezco tus consejos, los pondré en práctica.

Comment: Me parece muy difícil hacer algo más sencillo que tres líneas de código para tres operaciones de copia, ¿puedes señalar en concreto qué es lo que no entiendes e intento añadir más detalles?

Comment: Sé que no hace falta agredecer solo con puntuar basta. Pero igual muchas gracias por la explicación y por tu tiempo, gran gran respuesta y muy bien explicada, ahora entendí!!!

Answer (score 1):

Por si te llega a interesar, tengo este método que es una alternativa a la que publicaste, no es más eficiente (o si), pero bueno.

```
void IntArr::addElement(int pos,int qtty, int *vec){
    if(used+qtty>size){
        espaciar(qtty);
    }
    int *aux=new int[size];
    if(pos<=0){
        for(int i=0;i<qtty;i++){
            aux[i]=vec[i];
        }
    int x=qtty;
    for(int i=0;i<used;i++){
        aux[x]=p[i];
        x++;
        }
    }

    if (pos>size || pos>used){
        for (int i=0;i<used;i++){
            aux[i]=p[i];
        }
        for (int i=0;i<qtty;i++){
            aux[used+i]=vec[i];
        }
    }

    if (pos>0 && pos<=used){
        for (int i=0;i<pos;i++){
            aux[i]=p[i];
        }
        for (int i=0;i<qtty;i++){
            aux[pos+i]=vec[i];
        }
        for (int i=pos;i<used;i++){
            aux[i+qtty]=p[i];
        }
    }

    used+=qtty;
    delete []p;
    p=aux;

}
```

Espero que te sea de ayuda Calvin. Y si no te fue de ayuda bueno no importa.

Comment: Muchas gracias señor Grisa!!!

Comment: No hay problema don, si quiere tengo otra función para insertar solo Un elemento en una posicion determinada

Comment: Esta bien gracias!!!

Comment: Aviso que no hay problema por pasarselo don.